# MS Test Elapsed Time Inconsistencies

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I am noticing that the elapsed time of my unit tests in Visual Studio 2013 Pro are only consistent when they are run via the same command. When the command changes the elapsed times change dramatically.

My specific situation is this: I have 4 passing tests, when I run them all using the "Run All" command in the Test Explorer window I get:

[image: Tests run via Run All command]

But, when I run those same 4 tests again, this time using the Run Passed Tests command, I get this:

[image: Tests run via Run Passed Tests]

Are these tests run in the sequence that they are listed in the Test Explorer?

Why does test1 take 16ms when I use Run All and then 1ms when I use Run Passing and test2 takes 4ms when I use Run All and 16ms when I use Run Passing?